# Erro na saída dos dados

Tags: c

Quero printar a saída exatamente como abaixo, mas o código vai dando a saída em cada entrada.

Entradas

- rmtpuzcafhnyxdesivlkbwgjqo
- 3
- roahp
- uhchch
- veras

Saídas

- veras
- batata
- wuvrl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char string[1000];
    char alfabeto[26];
    char misterio[1000];
    int N, i, tam, j, indice,z;

    scanf("%s", alfabeto);
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%s", string);
        tam = strlen(string);

        for(j = 0; j < tam; j++){
            string[j] = toupper(string[j]);
            indice = string[j] - 65;
            misterio[j] = alfabeto[indice];

        }
    printf("%s", misterio);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comece por separar na pergunta o que é código e o que é explicação do problema em si. Aproveite de detalhe sobre o que o seu programa supostamente deve fazer e em que parte não está a fazer o que é suposto.

Answer (score 2):

Oi, pelo que entendi você quer que as palavras sejam impressas nessa ordem que você colocou, então arrumei seu código para fazer isso. Talvez não seja a solução mais limpa, mas é bem prático:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char string[1000];
    char alfabeto[26];
    char misterio[1000];
    int N, i, tam, j, indice, z, aux=0;   //adicionei a variável aux

    scanf("%s", alfabeto);
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%s", string);
        tam = strlen(string);

        for(j = 0; j < tam; j++) {
            string[j] = toupper(string[j]);
            indice = string[j] - 65;
            misterio[aux] = alfabeto[indice];  //atenção aqui. aux nunca é zerado, sempre incrementado
            aux++;
        }
        misterio[aux] = '\n';  //adiciona o char que pula linha
        aux++;  //passa para a próxima casa do vetor
    }
    misterio[aux] = '\0';   //adiciona char que encerra a string

    printf("%s", misterio);

  return 0;
}
```

Eu coloquei a variável mistério pra guardar todas as palavras que você "traduziu". Basicamente, a string mistério guarda a palavra traduzida e então coloca um '\n', e segue assim até que acabem as entradas. Por fim é adicionado um '\0' para encerrar a string e printar sem símbolos errados.

Comment: solução muito boa :)

Comment: Mt obrigado mano!! '-'